# Ball with radius that tends to zero equal the point

Tags: real-analysis

Is it correct that in a metric space, for $B[x,r]$ an open ball centered in x with radiuis r: 
$\lim_{r\rightarrow0}B[x,r]=\{x\}$ or it is =$\emptyset$ ?

Thank you for the answers to this very basic question

Comment: Equals what point?

Comment: The center of the ball

Comment: Yes. For $r=0$, the open ball reduces to a singleton of its center since $d(x,x)=0<r$ for every positive $r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the limit alone means.

I think it's helpful to reframe the limit a bit more rigorously as:
$$ \lim_{r \to 0} B[x, r] = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B[x, \tfrac{1}{n}]. $$

Then, we can see that $x \in B[x, \tfrac{1}{n}] $ for all $n$.
It's not hard from here to show that if $ y \ne x$ implies that there is an $n$ such that $y \notin B[x, \tfrac{1}{n} ]$.

This shows that the limit is just the point.

Comment: Is it true either for an open and a closed ball?

Comment: Yeah. The reasoning above doesn't change if your ball is open or closed. $x$ is always in a ball centered at it, and you can always find such a $y$ regardless of whether your ball is open or closed.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I undestand.

Answer (score 0):

By definition $$B[x,r] = \{a : |x-a|< r \}$$ which means sending $r$ to $0$, we get $|x-a| \le 0$. This is true iff $x=a$.

Comment: Sorry, I mean an open ball

Comment: @JhonnyAnnunci That doesn't really matter